# Клик на Яндекс-карте в WebView в Android 6

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, webview, android-webview

Здравствуйте! 
Использую Yandex.Map API 2.0. в WebView Android-приложения. 
Требуется обработка клика по маркеру, установленному на карте. Сделано следующим образом:

```
myPlacemark.events.add('click', function (e) {
    callbackfunctions.targetAction();
});
```

Почти на всех устройствах работает, но возникла проблема под Android 6 на Samsung A5. Клики не обрабатываеются. Причем, клики по кнопкам zoom (+/-) на карте работают нормально.

Может у кого была похожая проблема? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема обострилась при переходе на API 2.1.
Причина была в том, что метки проставлялись до полной загрузки карты, т.е. оказывались "под" картой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить onclick на touchstart событие

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Но, не успел попробовать.